# How to run Environment specific impex in Hybris/SAP commerce cloud?

Tags: environment, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am trying to run impex environment specifically. Need to create  impex which will run in all the environments, Otherwise I need to create multiple impexes. Please help.

Need a single impex which can run in all environments, with env specific data.

Answer (score 1):

```
#% impex.enableCodeExecution(true);

###########################################################
# Execute scripts based on the current environment setting
###########################################################

#% if: "ENV_ID".equals(Config.getParameter("environmentId"));

# ------------------------------
# Begin Environment-Specific ImpEx
# ------------------------------

# Place your environment-specific ImpEx commands here

# ------------------------------
# End Environment-Specific ImpEx
# ------------------------------

#% endif:
```

Explanation:

This ImpEx structure utilizes conditional execution. It checks the value of the environmentId property, and if this value matches "ENV_ID", the enclosed ImpEx commands will be executed. By changing "ENV_ID" to the desired environment identifier and adding your specific ImpEx commands within the structure, you can tailor the script to different environments.

Note: Ensure the environmentId property is set correctly for each environment in the appropriate properties file or configuration source.